# Is induced subgraph isomorphism easy on an infinite subclass?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Is there a sequence of undirected graphs $\{C_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, where each $C_n$ has exactly $n$ vertices and the problem

> Given $n$ and a graph $G$, is $C_n$ an induced subgraph of $G$?

is known to be in class $\mathsf{P}$?

Comment: Where does this question come from, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @Raphael - The question popped into my head after seeing http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10573. I don't have intuition what the answer is - either there should be a nice family of graphs (perhaps an increasing chain) where finding the subgraph is easier because of the structure of the graphs, or a reduction from something NP-hard. For example, Ramsey's theorem states that for large $n$, there should be clique or independent set, but the dependency in $n$ is too weak to make a reduction.

Comment: Set $C_n$ as complete graph of size $n$, then is easy to verify given graph is induced subgraph of one of a $C_n$ (in $P$). I don't know, may be I didn't get your question.

Comment: @Saeed: It's the other way round: the problem is asking if $C_n \leq G$, which is the NP-complete clique problem (note that $G$ does not have to have $n$ vertices)

Comment: @sdcvvc, I read your question in reverse, I though you checking is G is subgraph of any C_n, my mistake.

Comment: Crossposted to [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16998)

Comment: Since the cross-post has been answered, this question should be closed.

Comment: @frafl I think referring to the other answer with a CW answer is a good way to solve this, as we can not close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered [on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17025/13836).

Digest: [Chen,Thurley and Weyer (2008)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1427956) prove that this problem is $W[1]$-hard for every infinite class of graphs.